# Installing Steam in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, steam

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.10. Steam is showing up in the Ubuntu Software Center, but when I click on it it says:

> **Not found**
>   <sup>There isn't a software package called "steam" in your current software sources.</sup>

[image]

Is there a fix for this? Am I the only one having this problem?

Comment: Get the Steam package from the official website. Here's a link: `http://store.steampowered.com/about/`. If you meet any error do `sudo apt-get -f install` to install dependencies.

Answer (score 36):

First Update the system. Then try with commandline as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package steam`

Comment: -1 the package was removed in 14.10

Comment: +1 It appears that it has been readded in 15.10.

Comment: This answer only works for Ubuntu 32-bit. Steam is part of the "multiverse" repository, but [only the 32-bit version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steam&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). If you have use 64-bit, check the other answers.

Answer (score 11):

Steam can be install as a flatpak package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak # required in 16.04 only, not in later releases
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.valvesoftware.Steam
```

Steam can be launched by clicking on its icon in the Dash or launched from the terminal with the following command:

```
flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam
```

Many games require an online purchase, but some popular games, such as Team Fortress 2, are free to play. When searching in the store, be sure to narrow results by the SteamOS/Linux operating system. Not all Linux games are compatible with your system, so make sure you check the requirements before purchasing games.

Comment: For 64-bit Ubuntu, see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/706073/110157

Answer (score 8):

The `steam` package is [part of the "multiverse" repository for Ubuntu versios 14.04 onwards](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steam&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), but **only for 32 bit versions of Ubuntu**. If you want the 64-bit Steam package, ***you need to add the Steam repository to your sources***.

## 32-bit Ubuntu

- enable the "multiverse" repository
- run `sudo apt-get update`
- Install `steam` using either `apt-get` or the Software Center.

## 64-bit Ubuntu

- add  the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

  > deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
- run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam-launcher`

or

- install the `.deb` manually from [the official site](http://store.steampowered.com/about/).

Answer (score 4):

If it is not possible to find in the Software Center and not possible to install .deb file, then add the source in the software center manually.

```
Source = deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
```

Now possible to install it !

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Comment: It should be possible to install it like that without adding the source.

Comment: @Tim Only in the 32-bit version. `steam` is part of the "multiverse" repository, but [only the 32-bit version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steam&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Answer (score 2):

Using Xubuntu 14.10 x64, from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam
```

This will download and install Steam.  Accept the EULA, update Steam, then sign in with your Steam login.  BAM!  Steam on Xubuntu!

Comment: This answer only works for Ubuntu 32-bit. Steam is part of the "multiverse" repository, but [only the 32-bit version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steam&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). If you have use 64-bit, check the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that using

`sudo apt-get install steam`

works fine (still I don't know why steam seems not available on Software Center), however if the application does not appear in menu it is not necessary rebooting, just run

`sudo updatedb`

Comment: Do you use 14.10 or another version?

Comment: Add the time of the above message, I was using 14.10, recently I installed Steam on a 15.04 without any problem

Comment: I don't get why -2 points?

Comment: This answer only works for Ubuntu 32-bit. Steam is part of the "multiverse" repository, but [only the 32-bit version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steam&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). If you have use 64-bit, check the other answers.

Comment: Is this something new? When I wrote that answer I was using a 64bit machine and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the Steam package manually.

Go to http://store.steampowered.com/about/ and choose the "Install Steam now" link.  This will download a debian package (ends in `.deb`) which you can open directly in the Ubuntu Software Center app.  The "Install" button will then install Steam.

It appears it does not show up in the launchbar, but you can search for it (tap the Windows button) and launch it.  When launched right-click on the icon to lock it to the launch bar.
You can then search for the Steam

Answer (score 0):

If the `apt-get install steam` doesn't work do the followings

```
wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```

you may have to `rm -r ~/.steam ~/.local/share/Steam` directory for removing the old config

If you have **problems** installing or running it, try [following question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)