# Error downloading steam

Tags: package-management, downloads, steam

After downloading steam, it requires me to download the packages `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`, and `libc6:i386`. However, when I attempt do do so I get this error message:

```
E: unable to locate package libl1-mesa-dri:i386
E: unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
E: unable to locate package libc6:i386
```

How can I download them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Steam in Ubuntu 14.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/546580/installing-steam-in-ubuntu-14-10). Remove the existing Steam before you install the version of Steam that is provided by the default Ubuntu repositories

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unable to locate package" while trying to install packages by apt](http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *downloading* Steam, open a terminal window (`Ctrl + Alt + T`) and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge steam
```

Press ENTER. Your password will be requested, type it and press ENTER again. This command will remove Steam if it was installed with errors.

Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

And press ENTER. Wait for the process to end, and steam will be installed on your computer, including all of the needed packages.

**Note**: *I am posting this answer assuming that you downloaded Steam directly from your browser.*

**EDIT**: If everything works, a Steam Launcher should appear in your Desktop. If this does not happen, open a terminal window and type

```
steam
```

And then press ENTER.
Also, if you really want to install those packages, remove that :i386. For example, instead of `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` use `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri`. Seems that i386 only indicates that you need a 32-bit package.

Comment: I still get the same error...

Comment: even if you try installing all the packages without :i386?