# Repository Error while installing steam from Ubuntu software store

Tags: error-handling

Why am I getting this error?How to solve it

[image: Error]

**edit 1:**

When I type steam in terminal window,steam opens but these lines are autmatically written in terminal window.Also note that when I close the terminal window,the steam application also closes.

```
rajatendu@rajatendu-450R4J-450R4Q-451R4J-4450RJ:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
process 11709: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1201.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 109 milliseconds to initialize
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
CApplicationManagerPopulateThread took 332 milliseconds to initialize (will have waited on CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown device type 13

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4: unknown object type

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: handle_property_changed: failed to update property 'devices' of object type NMActiveConnection.

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown device type 14

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1: unknown object type

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown device type 13

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4: unknown object type

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown device type 16

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5: unknown object type

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'autoconnect-priority'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'interface-name'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'dns-priority'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'dns-priority'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'bridge'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: replace_settings: error updating connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4 settings: (3) type

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'autoconnect-priority'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'interface-name'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'dns-priority'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'dns-priority'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'bridge'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: replace_settings: error updating connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4 settings: (3) type

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Unknown setting 'proxy'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'route-data'

** (steam:11709): WARNING **: Ignoring invalid property 'address-data'
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
[0330/131510.587297:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
process 11779: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1201.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
[0330/131511.588134:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Could not create Vulkan instance : 
ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT
[0330/131512.589173:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 769
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198304956101 [API loaded no]
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
[0330/131513.592244:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
roaming config store loaded successfully - 620 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 11709: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
ExecCommandLine: "'/home/rajatendu/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam'"
System startup time: 11.68 seconds

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
Generating new string page texture 74: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 1.36 MB
Generating new string page texture 75: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131.07 KB
Generating new string page texture 76: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.49 MB
Generating new string page texture 77: 64x256, total string texture memory is 1.56 MB
Generating new string page texture 78: 32x256, total string texture memory is 1.59 MB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:11709): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
Generating new string page texture 89: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.72 MB
Generating new string page texture 91: 256x256, total string texture memory is 1.98 MB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522101301)
^C
```

Comment: Are you using 17.04?

Comment: 17.10 (64 bit) Ubuntu

Comment: What are the results of the command `apt policy steam` ? If it shows Steam in the results get some more information about Steam's dependencies with the command: `apt show steam` and maybe you can install steam from the terminal instead of with the Software app.

Comment: @karel when I type steam in terminal ,steam is opened.So I am able to use steam.That,means steam is installed.But the question remains that how can I solve this error and install steam from the Ubuntu software centre?Can you list the steps and commands?

Comment: This is an old problem (see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diNzf.png)) and it still hasn't been solved so you're stuck with using the terminal like this question: [Installing Steam in Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546580/installing-steam-in-ubuntu-14-10/546597#546597)