# How to get Steam to properly install

Tags: package-management, software-installation, steam

I am very new to ubuntu and Linux and kind of scraping by as I've only been a PC gamer since December of last year. I used steam on my little garbage Lenovo using Windows 10, but after getting my I5 HP I had to run Ubuntu because the hard reset caused Windows to corrupt on login. While trying to get steam on, I used Ubuntu Software and the terminal yet when I find the desktop/applications icon, nothing happens. it doesn't load up, it doesn't prompt me, literally all it did was after installation it updated. Can someone please help a noob out and let me know what I can do to get it to run?

---

**EDIT I:**

My specs are:

Processor - Intel Core i5 52OOU
  RAM - 6GB 2GB- 1X 4GB skHynix
  GPU - Intel 5500 HD graphics
  HDD - 500GB Toshiba HDD

I did `sudo apt install steam` which would install steam. But as said, it seemed installed but I couldn't find it in Downloads and when using the terminal to open Steam I got

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/avery/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

---

**EDIT II:**

I tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam-launcher`, but this is what came up:

```
avery@Avery-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam-launcher
[sudo] password for avery: 
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725) bionic Release
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]    
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Fetched 158 kB in 1s (222 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam-launcher
```

---

**EDIT III:**

I used    `/etc/apt/sources.list :deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/precise steam`     and    `bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied`    came up.

**EDIT IV**

After I ran `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, all this came up.

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bio$

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
```

This is what happened with the code you've given me. Do i need to install steam and try it?  currently i dont have steam or the steam installer from Ubuntu Software.

---

**EDIT V**
This is everything in my steam file since i downloaded it the first time on. This code comes from a file inside steam called *bootstrap_log.txt
Is this helpful to a solution?

```
[2018-11-14 18:07:13] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
[2018-11-14 18:07:13] Verifying installation...
[2018-11-14 18:07:13] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/avery/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2018-11-14 18:07:13] Verification complete
[2018-11-14 18:07:13] Downloading Update...
[2018-11-14 18:07:13] Checking for available update...
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.1ca83d76835b4613170f5cead778b176b11f2b0c missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.3[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.1ca83d76835b4613170f5cead778b176b11f2b0c missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.33245b7d523f68418283e93b0572508fa127ee8f missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.vz.7673e4cd32b6752bc621d8bc1a7118a9af19b64a_12077027 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.89b80bcfdd11b2b99257ddbbdc374e2df54e2738 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.vz.ffef2b2fc386819a842ea79484b966a937c2ca7e_1209792 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_images_all.zip.vz.04fa59fdcdeb3818196294fb1db417f75a46d1ec_31242830 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file tenfoot_all.zip.vz.545c24ee33b60f736e9e9ac975fe30df8fb124a8_2569861 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file friendsui_all.zip.vz.3c4a7f86d9c15bca782499b76024765b2ff8376f_3087851 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file resources_misc_all.zip.vz.4a1fa88d21b005b67a41a9a0fc6044ae1fa46791_2225211 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file resources_music_all.zip.vz.7a62e15083d4a65668f0d1fa58ad8c1b99fb5ace_3708050 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file resources_hidpi_all.zip.vz.3c5bd3d518c854fea3680ca96768205dee63c1bb_50023 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file resources_all.zip.vz.b9dea6fa681b2a51f558e7956b58e62bc6f665c9_1284584 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file strings_en_all.zip.vz.0656d1b3cd09795b3e1f80c9b2743a8ca2b72c52_88986 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file strings_all.zip.vz.739a0611857cf29c90287c9acb41637023059d73_2234555 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file public_all.zip.vz.627a2db5151c33614fc96e9593a24960120a7c8a_792660 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.42b2836b46de63035015b651f377fe67d342b3d8_17874047 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.96531d903ab1ac3c9d17a6764c5601a6f3027db6_9046128 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.vz.7797e33f4b28cb9df9579020743e946b7c9928af_12082781 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.vz.228ce3d6bd2f702a390c63cef6158d21ba57c9e5_2373711 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.vz.531    deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bio$

    # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
    # newer versions of the distribution.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

    ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
    ## distribution.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

    ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
    ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

    ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
    ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
    ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
    ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
    ## security team.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

    ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
    ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes

    ^G Get Help    ^O Write Out   ^W Where Is    ^K Cut Text    ^J Justify
    ^X Exit        ^R Read File   ^\ Replace     ^U Uncut Text  ^T To Spell16ac89ba46dd007b93073094a896a84f9560e_1554554 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.9ef83abe859bbdc31fbd213ee273c9dced55e5f0_49643930 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file miles_ubuntu12.zip.vz.4fd048667c97ef6eb976f4c42ce5c18f8695ac9e_295483 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.vz.cf46e688ed508b3d2a46e968f21beb6fca20ac1e_653738 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file steam_ubuntu12.zip.vz.b397288f03a7cebeb7a79cb09527c863c652da59_1505082 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.789d32b0d1b0bfcb469b78711452314a493bdaab missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Package file runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.5cfff6f643c830be371264dec3864148f874187e missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Downloading update (853 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Downloading update (2,466 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:14] Downloading update (3,911 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:15] Downloading update (5,111 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:15] Downloading update (6,338 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:15] Downloading update (7,387 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:15] Downloading update (8,448 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:16] Downloading update (9,533 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:16] Downloading update (10,568 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:16] Downloading update (11,456 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:16] Downloading update (12,417 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:17] Downloading update (13,538 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:17] Downloading update (14,675 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:17] Downloading update (15,769 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:17] Downloading update (16,748 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:18] Downloading update (17,689 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:18] Downloading update (18,572 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:18] Downloading update (19,599 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:18] Downloading update (20,669 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:19] Downloading update (21,959 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:19] Downloading update (23,165 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:19] Downloading update (24,170 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:19] Downloading update (25,196 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:20] Downloading update (26,231 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:20] Shutdown
287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:20] Downloading update (38,235 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:20] Downloading update (40,203 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:20] Downloading update (41,990 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:20] Downloading update (43,574 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:21] Downloading update (45,176 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:21] Downloading update (46,956 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:21] Downloading update (48,630 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:21] Downloading update (50,296 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:22] Downloading update (52,097 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:22] Downloading update (53,685 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:22] Downloading update (55,464 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:22] Downloading update (57,244 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:23] Downloading update (58,873 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:23] Downloading update (60,664 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:23] Downloading update (62,279 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:24] Downloading update (63,944 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:24] Downloading update (65,488 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:24] Downloading update (67,202 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:24] Downloading update (68,891 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:25] Downloading update (70,553 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:25] Downloading update (72,263 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:25] Downloading update (74,043 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:25] Downloading update (75,687 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:26] Downloading update (77,308 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:26] Downloading update (79,048 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:26] Downloading update (80,808 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:26] Downloading update (82,566 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:27] Downloading update (84,069 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:27] Downloading update (85,854 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:27] Downloading update (87,642 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:27] Downloading update (89,408 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:28] Downloading update (90,889 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:28] Downloading update (92,649 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:28] Downloading update (94,363 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:28] Downloading update (96,082 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:29] Downloading update (97,698 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:29] Downloading update (99,480 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:29] Downloading update (101,255 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:29] Downloading update (103,059 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:30] Downloading update (104,669 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:30] Downloading update (106,448 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:30] Downloading update (108,201 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:30] Downloading update (109,970 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:31] Downloading update (111,512 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:31] Downloading update (113,228 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:31] Downloading update (115,001 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:31] Downloading update (116,692 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:32] Downloading update (118,281 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:32] Downloading update (120,150 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:32] Downloading update (122,305 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:32] Downloading update (124,079 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:33] Downloading update (125,618 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:33] Downloading update (127,260 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:33] Downloading update (129,576 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:34] Downloading update (131,283 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:34] Downloading update (133,106 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:34] Downloading update (134,687 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:34] Downloading update (136,347 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:35] Downloading update (137,970 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:35] Downloading update (139,739 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:35] Downloading update (141,531 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:35] Downloading update (143,386 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:36] Downloading update (145,003 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:36] Downloading update (146,630 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:36] Downloading update (148,363 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:36] Downloading update (150,179 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:37] Downloading update (151,668 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:37] Downloading update (153,363 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:37] Downloading update (155,110 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:37] Downloading update (156,860 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:38] Downloading update (158,481 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:38] Downloading update (160,264 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:38] Downloading update (161,975 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:38] Downloading update (163,709 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:39] Downloading update (165,312 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:39] Downloading update (167,036 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:39] Downloading update (168,794 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:39] Downloading update (170,476 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:40] Downloading update (172,078 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:40] Downloading update (173,840 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:40] Downloading update (175,618 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:40] Downloading update (177,195 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:41] Downloading update (178,681 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:41] Downloading update (180,479 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:41] Downloading update (182,275 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:41] Downloading update (183,927 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:42] Downloading update (185,562 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:42] Downloading update (187,341 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:42] Downloading update (189,061 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:42] Downloading update (190,766 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:43] Downloading update (192,416 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:43] Downloading update (194,076 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:43] Downloading update (195,837 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:43] Downloading update (197,587 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:44] Downloading update (199,203 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:44] Downloading update (200,975 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:44] Downloading update (202,692 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:44] Downloading update (204,466 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:45] Downloading update (205,992 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:45] Downloading update (207,784 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:45] Downloading update (209,523 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:45] Downloading update (211,124 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:46] Downloading update (212,895 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:46] Downloading update (214,682 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:46] Downloading update (216,458 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:46] Downloading update (218,056 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:47] Downloading update (219,838 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:47] Downloading update (221,616 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:47] Downloading update (223,369 of    deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bio$

    # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
    # newer versions of the distribution.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

    ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
    ## distribution.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

    ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
    ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

    ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
    ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
    ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
    ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
    ## security team.
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
    deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
    # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

    ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
    ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes

    ^G Get Help    ^O Write Out   ^W Where Is    ^K Cut Text    ^J Justify
    ^X Exit        ^R Read File   ^\ Replace     ^U Uncut Text  ^T To Spell 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:47] Downloading update (224,960 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:48] Downloading update (226,765 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:48] Downloading update (228,546 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:48] Downloading update (230,298 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:48] Downloading update (231,925 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:49] Downloading update (233,570 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:49] Downloading update (235,322 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:49] Downloading update (236,967 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:49] Downloading update (238,651 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:50] Downloading update (240,429 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:50] Downloading update (242,230 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:50] Downloading update (243,808 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:50] Downloading update (245,604 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:51] Downloading update (247,338 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:51] Downloading update (249,131 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:51] Downloading update (250,651 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:51] Downloading update (252,197 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:52] Downloading update (253,984 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:52] Downloading update (255,568 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:52] Downloading update (257,358 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:52] Downloading update (259,144 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:53] Downloading update (260,720 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:53] Downloading update (262,310 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:53] Downloading update (264,085 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:53] Downloading update (265,674 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:54] Downloading update (267,432 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:54] Downloading update (268,972 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:54] Downloading update (271,716 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:55] Downloading update (272,910 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:55] Downloading update (273,977 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:55] Downloading update (275,182 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:55] Downloading update (276,346 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:56] Downloading update (277,541 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:56] Downloading update (278,494 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:56] Downloading update (279,507 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:56] Downloading update (280,716 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:57] Downloading update (281,910 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:57] Downloading update (283,058 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:07:58] Downloading update (283,658 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:08:14] Error: Download of package (resources_music_all) failed after 0 bytes (0).
[2018-11-14 18:08:14] Package file resources_music_all.zip.vz.7a62e15083d4a65668f0d1fa58ad8c1b99fb5ace_3708050 missing or incorrect size
[2018-11-14 18:08:14] Downloading update (283,893 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:08:15] Downloading update (284,570 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:08:15] Downloading update (285,241 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:08:15] Downloading update (285,830 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:08:15] Downloading update (286,452 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:08:16] Downloading update (287,094 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:08:16] Downloading update (287,279 of 287,279 KB)...
[2018-11-14 18:08:16] Download Complete.
[2018-11-14 18:08:16] uninstalled manifest found in /home/avery/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2018-11-14 18:08:16] Found pending update
[2018-11-14 18:08:16] Applying update...
[2018-11-14 18:08:16] Extracting package...
[2018-11-14 18:08:29] Installing update...
[2018-11-14 18:08:30] Cleaning up...
[2018-11-14 18:08:30] Update complete, launching...
[2018-11-14 18:08:30] Shutdown
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly explain exactly what you have done so far. Tell us commands you used, and complete results, Avoid summarizing.

Comment: Also tell us about your Ubuntu version and hardware specifications (or at least the HP model), especialy graphics cards and drivers (if you installed any).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Steam in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546580/installing-steam-in-ubuntu) This answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/546580/installing-steam-in-ubuntu/546597#546597

Comment: when you are trying to add lines inside any file u need to do that with an editor. Do `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` Make sure you replace **precise** with your codename. You can look up your codename by entering `lsb_release -a` in terminal. Before editing the file do `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list/ /etc/apt/sources.list-backup` so you can restore your sources list in case of misconfiguration

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help so far, its very appreciated.

Comment: "literally all it did was after installation it updated" this often causes a problem. Can you run `steam` in a terminal and post the output?

Comment: What do you mean by the output? if you look above in my first edit, I posted the output it gave me when i used     `steam`

Comment: When you run `steam` you get an error from `tar`?? I assumed you were running a `tar` command to get that error

Comment: Possible? I simply would put in `steam` after i installed it via `sudo apt-get install steam`.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Steam I was running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I used the cmd line to install with:

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

From there I can find the icon in my applications or I run it from the cmd line with:

```
steam
```

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and everything still works, although I believe in install syntax now is:

```
sudo apt install steam
```

I always update before I install anything:

```
sudo apt-get update or sudo apt update
```

Comment: I think OP probably already did this. It's kind of hard to tell. FYI, `apt` is just a new interface for APT - `apt-get` still works. [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](//askubuntu.com/q/445384)

Comment: apt-get update in 18.04 didn't work properly where apt update did.