# Help installing steam

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, steam

I'm brand new to Ubuntu and trying to install steam.  I downloaded steam_latest.deb and installed it, but whenever I try to open it it gives me this:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 

libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386

E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

E: Unable to locate package libc6:i386

Press return to continue:
```

Literally any help is appreciated I am so lost ;v;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Steam in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546580/installing-steam-in-ubuntu) - See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546580/installing-steam-in-ubuntu/546597#546597)

Answer (score 1):

You might not have support for 32-bit architecture (i386) enabled.  It is disabled by default in 64-bit installs.  Try this from the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then update your package list

```
sudo apt update
```

Try opening Steam again, and hopefully you will now be able to install the needed packages.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work,  I'm actually pretty bad at this kinda stuff so I might have screwed it up.  The only difference now is instead of not being able to locate package 'libc6:i386' it "has no installation candidate"

Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate

Comment: The 32-bit architecture was dropped since 18.04. Please remove it with `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386` (reverses the wrong suggestion in this answer) otherwise you won't probably be able to install anything else, including critical updates.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia i386 IS supported for packages still in 18.04.  There are no 32bit INSTALLER images but the arch and packages FOR IT do still exist in the repositories.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but not all. We've seen this problem also with Atom. And Steam should be installed like I described, no i386 dependencies. Adding i386 will give errors everywhere.... Pretty much

Comment: @ThomasWard Added additional steps to correct the two mistakes already made by the OP (neither of their own fault actually). If it's up to your standards now please remove the negative vote. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I believe you are mistaken. I am running the official Steam .deb from the steampowered site on 18.04 with multiarch support enabled, and it works just fine. These other sources confirm that the official Steam .deb using i386 support installs and runs on both 18.04 and 18.10.  http://www.theubuntumaniac.com/2018/11/how-to-install-latest-steam-on-ubuntu.html https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux I am sorry to hear that the OP was still having trouble after following my suggestion, but would you mind removing your downvote?